# Plugins are not reflecting from nexus

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, nexus

I have uploaded my artifacts to nexus using maven-deploy as a common-dependency-manager for all projects. I have included some plugins jacoco, checkstyle in parent pom which is deployed into nexus. Below is the **child-pom** used to download artifacts from nexus. When I run **mvn install** I am not able to see any changes/reports get generated for the plugins.

In settings.xml I didn't make any changes(I shouldn't)

```
<dependencies> (Deployed Artifacts mentioned in local child pom)
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <URL><nexusurl>/repository/testing/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <URL><nexusurl>/repository/testing/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

I didn't find any solution anywhere. May I know what is the error I made?

Comment: Ah i see that i misunderstood the question. You'll need to post the plugin section of the parent pom so that we can see how you have the plugins configured. And some of the child pom as well so that we can see if you included the parent correctly.

Comment: Also this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078745/jacoco-maven-multi-module-project-coverage

Comment: Hi Joe, This is my (Plugins Section) [Parent Pom](https://github.com/AnuragSanagapalli/parentpom/blob/master/pom.xml) and Child Pom I have already mentioned in the question, I didn't mention anything apart from that.

Comment: The Link you shared it will work when Parent Pom is in local. But here I am using from the nexus, so I tried the same but no success.

Comment: Can you post the child pom where you set the parent? That isn't included in your post. The link should apply no matter whether the parent is remote or local. the process is the same.

Comment: <dependencies> (Deployed Artifacts mentioned in local child pom)
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

By using this I am downloading the artifacts mentioned in child Pom in the dependency section. Should I do it in Parent Section?

Comment: <parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
 </parent>
I tried with parent but same issue persists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216911/discussion-between-anuragsanagapalli-and-joe-w).